# Alert message if date and time is older than a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a date and time field, the date field consists of 3 fields: *day*, *month* and *year*. And time field consists of 2 fields, *hour* and *minute*.

I want to show an alert if the date is older than 2 months and 60 hours.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-date">
    <div class="date_day">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_day" id="input_day" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_month">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_month" id="input_month" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_year>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="input_year" id="input_year" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-time">
    <div class="time_hour>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_hour" id="input_hour" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="time_minute">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_minute" id="input_minute" value="">
    </div>     
</div>
```

I can do it with one field only for date, but have now 3 fields that I need.

I tried something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var day = $('#input_day');
    var month = $('#input_month');
    var year = $('#input_year');

    var today = new Date();
    var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

    month.on("input change", function() {
        if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (this + 11) > 4) {
            console.log('test');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Convert your data to Long format (in milliseconds), let it name `var a`
Get your local time `var date = new Date(); var now = date.getTime();`
Now, calculate `now - a`, it should be less than `(2 * 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + (60 * 60 * 1000)`, otherwise, it is older than you want

Comment: You have tried something?  See about [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), you can use [Date#getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)  to compare date distance with [Date#now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now)

Comment: I tried something like this: 

`jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var dayfield = $('#input_day');
 var monthfield = $('#input_month');
 var yearfield = $('#input_year');

 var today = new Date();
 var date = $(this);

    monthfield.on("input change", function() {
  
  if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (date.getMonth() + 11) > 3) {
         var $error = $( "<div id='error-message' class='error-message'><p>Error</p></div>" );
         $("#content").append($error);
     }

 });


}); `

But not worked @MehdiAlgholipour @CiroSpaciari

Comment: @CiroSpaciari yes I tried something like `jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 var day = $('#input_day');
 var month = $('#input_month');
 var year = $('#input_year');

 var today = new Date();
 var currentMonth = today.getMonth();

    month.on("input change", function() {
  if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (this + 11) > 4) {
         console.log('test');
     }
 });


}); `

Comment: and what was the result? What was the expected result? What was the logic behind `if ((today.getMonth() + 11) - (this + 11) > 4)`?? I cannot grasp what the thinking was. Apart from `this` being an element and not a number, I can't see where 11 or 4 would come into it. And your hours?

Comment: @ADyson I don't get a console, the expected result was that it shows the console test if the entered month is older than 4 months

Comment: Yes, you already said that bit. But give an example. What did you input? And again, what was the logic of those tests? It makes no sense at all as far as I can see. I cannot follow the reasoning which would lead to such code.

Comment: I input 4 in the input field of months @ADyson

Comment: `this` should be `this.value` because `this` represents the textbox, not the text within it.

Comment: @ADyson I tried `this.value and this.val` but not working.

Comment: You perhaps need to parse the value as an int, since you're inputting a string. Anyway, test data: https://jsfiddle.net/p0fva6o2/ . Some don't appear to return the right result, probably due to your inexplicable logic, and not sure how you expected to get hours when you only asses the month? I'm fascinated by the logic which caused you to arrive at this bizarre algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to parse the form date, create the comparison date according to the expected period and then return if the formDate is greater than comparisonDate.

Please, let me know if the code below is according to what you expected:

```js
function getFormDate() {
    const formYear = $("#input_year").val();
    const formMonth = $("#input_month").val() - 1;
    const formDay = $("#input_day").val();
    const formHour = $("#input_hour").val();
    const formMinute = $("#input_minute").val();
    return new Date(formYear, formMonth, formDay, formHour, formMinute, 0, 0)
}

function getComparisonDate() {
    const today = new Date()
    let comparisonDate = new Date()
    comparisonDate.setMonth(today.getMonth() - 2)
    comparisonDate.setHours(today.getHours() - 60)
    return comparisonDate
}

function thereIsMissingValue() {
    let anyMissing = false;
    const inputs = $(".container-date input, .container-time input")
    inputs.each(function () {
        if (!$(this).val())
            anyMissing = true
    });
    return anyMissing
}

function displayMessage() {
    const formDate = getFormDate()
    const comparisonDate = getComparisonDate()

    $("#min-allowed-date").text(comparisonDate.toLocaleString())

    const isOlderThanComparison = formDate < comparisonDate
    $(".older-date").toggle(isOlderThanComparison)

    const isInTheFuture = formDate > new Date()
    $(".future-date").toggle(isInTheFuture)

    const isValidDate = !isOlderThanComparison && !isInTheFuture
    $(".valid-date").toggle(isValidDate)
}

function calculate() {
    if (thereIsMissingValue()) {
        $(".container-date-validation").hide()
        return
    }
    $(".container-date-validation").show()

    displayMessage()
}

$('#input_year, #input_month, #input_day, #input_hour, #input_minute').change(function () { calculate(); })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-date">
    <div class="date_day">
        <label>Day</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_day" id="input_day" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_month">
        <label>Month</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_month" id="input_month" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_year">
        <label>Year</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="input_year" id="input_year" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-time">
    <div class="time_hour">
        <label>Hour</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_hour" id="input_hour" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="time_minute">
        <label>Minute</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_minute" id="input_minute" value="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-date-validation" style="display:none">
    <p class="older-date" style="display:none">Invalid date. Only dates after
        <span id="min-allowed-date"></span> are allowed.
    </p>
    <p class="future-date" style="display:none">Invalid date. It doesn't allow dates in the future.</p>
    <p class="valid-date">This is a valid date</p>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I say if is older do this? `if formDate < comparisonDate {
    alert("test");
   }` not working

Comment: This code should work. Could you please print content for "formDate" and "comparisonDate" to double check what is arriving to the if statement?

Comment: There are two missing quotes on original html that could be preventing some inputs to be found, it's worth to verify: <div class="date_year> and <div class="time_hour>

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Cacheta

Comment: I want to run the function on a change event of one of the input fields, to show an alert message and disable the button to go to the next step if the date is longer. 

I add this: 
 `$('#input_year, #input_month, #input_day, #input_hour, #input_minute').change(function(){
  calculate();
}) ` 

but the alert runs now multiple times on each change, do you know how to show the alert one time based on the input of the date?

Comment: This can be done by verifying if any of the inputs is still empty. I included the thereIsMissingValue method on the previous code to verify that, please let me know if it works as expected.

Comment: thanks mate  that works, learned a lot in this 2 days. You're Great. Last thing, I if edit a field twice (fill in and change) the alert run again. Is it possible to remove the first alert on editing/changing a field second time.

Comment: Glad to help. About editing twice, there are ways to handle that and not showing any message in this case, but I would probably want to check if the new value informed is still valid. Please, let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks mate, what are the ways to handle that?

Comment: Hi. According to the code you sent me, I suggest you to toggle the visibility on existing validation messages to avoid duplication. I updated the previous code with a suggestion on that, please let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you go with milliseconds :

2 months is 5184000000

60 hours is 216000000

total : 5400000000

the wantedDate will be new Date(year, month, day)

```
var wantedDate = new Date(year,month,day); // will create a date from the inputs
wantedDate.getTime() // will convert to miliseconds
```

and if you convert the wanted date to milliseconds you can easily find out

```
wantedDate < Date.now() && wantedDate > (Date.now() - 5400000000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really like using [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for things like this. It uses much more human-readable code, like so:

```
const moment = require('moment'); // assumes you install Moment as a node module

const month = $('#input_month');
const day = $('#input_day');
const year = $('#input_year');
const hour = $('#input_hour');
const minute = $('#input_minute');

const checkDate = () => {
    const inputDate = moment(month.val() + '/' + day.val() + '/' + year.val() + ' ' + hour.val() + ':' +  minute.val(), "MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm");
    const expDate = moment.subtract(2, "months").subtract(60, "hours");

    if (moment(inputDate).isBefore(expDate, "minute") {
        // do something
    }
}

month.on('change', checkDate);
```

You'll also need to ensure you're getting usable values from your inputs. I suggest using number input types or `select` menus to restrict input options.

Comment: gonna check this.